# Dictionary of Dictionaries - vba Office for Mac

Tags: macos, excel, dictionary, vba

In a nutshell, we get a report in excel from an application not our own that puts all the user responses from a single form into a single cell per submission.  I'm trying to write a VBA macro for Office:mac Excel.

So, a single cell in the "modifiers" column might appear like so:

**Cell 1:**
1st Teacher Choice|Gunderson;2nd Teacher Choice|Barnes;Do you like Jello?|Yes;Superman or Hulk?|Hulk

**Cell 2:**
1st Teacher Choice|Smith;2nd Teacher Choice|Gunderson;Do you like Jello?|Yes

**Cell 3:**
1st Teacher Choice|Wulfenbach;2nd Teacher Choice|Fontana;Do you like Jello?|No;Superman or Hulk?|Superman

**Cell 4:**
1st Teacher Choice|Fontana;2nd Teacher Choice|Smith;Do you like Jello?|Yes;Superman or Hulk?|Superman

**Cell 5:**
1st Teacher Choice|Heterodyne;2nd Teacher Choice|Wulfenback;Do you like Jello?|Yes;Superman or Hulk?|Superman

My objective is to collect all the questions (text between the ; and the |), create a column for each question, then populate the columns with the answers.  I envision the hash table as:

```
{
 "1st Teacher Choice":{1:"Gunderson", 2:"Smith", 3:"Wulfenbach", 4:"Fontana", 5:"Hetrodyne"},
 "2nd Teacher Choice":{1:"Barnes", 2:"Gunderson", 3:"Fontana", 4:"Smith", 5:"Wulfenbach"},
 "Do you like Jello?":{1:"yes", 2:"yes", 3:"no", 4:"yes", 5:"yes"},
 "Superman or Hulk":{1:"Hulk", 2:"",3:"Superman",4:"Superman",5:"Superman"}
}
```

Now, after all the preamble, here's the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
Dim modifierColumn As Integer
Dim rawModifiers As String
Dim oneMod As String
Dim oneResp As String

Dim modifierList As Dictionary
Set modifierList = New Dictionary

For theRow = 2 To lastRow
    'Get the string of modifiers in the current row
    rawModifiers = Cells(theRow, modifierColumn).value
    'Break each modifier string in the row into a separate array element
    rowModifiersArray = Split(rawModifiers, ";")
    'Iterate through each of the modifiers and value in the new array
    For Each modResp In rowModifiersArray
        'Seperate the modifier from the response in another temp array, 'singleModifier’.
        'The first element of the array will be the name of the modifier, the second will be the response to the modifier.
        singleModifier = Split(modResp, "|")
        oneMod = singleModifier(0)
        oneResp = singleModifier(1)
        'If the modifier exists as a key in the ModifierList, add the row and the value into the dictionary associated to that key
        'If the modifier has already been entered in modifierList, add the row and value to the sub-dictionary
        If (Not modifierList.Exists(oneMod)) Then
            modifierList.Add oneMod, New Dictionary
        End If
        'ERROR IS THROWN ON LINE BELOW
        modifierList(oneMod).Add theRow, oneResp
    Next
Next theRow
```

The above code merely creates the hash table.  Creating the columns after that is pretty straightforward so I will leave it out for the purposes of this question.

I've installed the add-in **Dictionary** and **KeyValue** classes created by Patrick O'Bierne at [his excellent blog](http://sysmod.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/dictionary-class-in-vba-instead-of-scripting-dictionary/).  However, I get a runtime error ('438') stating "Object doesn't support this property or method" at the third line from the bottom, marked by a comment.  The first Dictionary .Add method worked fine.  Any ideas?  Could this be an error in the class implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to be a little more explicit

Instead of

```
modifierList(oneMod).Add theRow, oneResp
```

Try this

```
modifierList.KeyValuePairs(oneMod).value.Add theRow, oneResp
```

Comment: That was it!  Although apparently Dictionaries REQUIRE you to have an index that is NOT an integer (yuck!), so I had to tweak your answer just a bit:

`modifierList.KeyValuePairs(oneMod).value.Add CStr(theRow), oneResp`